# Sklearn GaussianProcessRegressor fixing kernel hyperparameters?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian

I'm trying to use sklearn's gaussian process for timeseries decomposition.

```
kernel = ConstantKernel() * 
RBF() *
ExpSineSquared(periodicity=7)
```

Is there a way to fix the parameters other then `periodicity_bounds=(7, 7)`

If i do `kernel.hyperparameters` i can see they have a attribute `fixed=False`

How do i set this to true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its not documented on the Kernels them self. But the hyper parameters can fixed by the following.

```
ExpSineSquared(periodicity=7, periodicity_bounds='fixed')
```

Comment: You can find the documentation of the Hyperparameter class here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.Hyperparameter.html
Indeed, the bound attributes can take "fixed" if you want the hyperparameter's value cannot be changed.